# I have just installed android SDK updates and now my projects are full of errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I recently just installed downloaded and installed some updates in the android sdk to get access to some features and now when I have restarted eclipse all the projects have errors!! 
Theres a small error at the start of package and the only resolutions it suggests is reconfigure build path, here is a picture of the carnage. Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Project -> Clean may be?

Comment: Close/Opne eclipse - I am sure you tried already, but..

Comment: ahh thats done it never installed properly, ta man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `java.util` is an offending import, you haven't got your JRE configured properly or either the build or the IDE are in a kind of corrupted state. Since you already used the *Clean* command I'm going for a more complex issue.

Check your project's configuration and make sure you're not still referencing your old Java implementation. If by installing updates you mean that you downloaded a new version, installed it and then deleted the one you've been using so far, then the IDE might not be finding the JRE system library your project has currently configured.

Try right clicking your project > *Build Path* > *Configure build path*, then check if your current JRE system library is *unbound*. If so, you'll have to configure it again on the *Libraries* tab by using *Add Library* > *JRE System Library*.